# Customize Opportunity - Related List Stage History

Tags: opportunity, related-list, opportunity-history, field-history

I have a requirement where I need to add fields in stage history related list. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry we cannot add any fields in that reated list.

Comment: but i need to show an amount field which is a roll up summary of child custom object

Comment: Then simply use a workflow to update the value of that toll up summary to that amount fild which is being displayed in stage history related list.